# Unable to generate PMML file with ctree

Tags: r, pmml

I am using "iris" data on R to do a decision tree analysis. Now the problem is that every thing works fine in terms of getting output using print and plots, but when i try to generate the PMML file using ctree , I am having the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("pmml") : 
  no applicable method for 'pmml' applied to an object of class "c('BinaryTree', 'BinaryTreePartition')"
```

With the rpart library though i am able to generate the PMML successfully, but i am unable to figure out why pmml is not generated with ctree. I am putting both the working and non working outcome

```
Not-working:
============
library("party")
iris_ctree <- ctree(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris)
pmml(iris_ctree)
[ I am getting error over here , which i mentioned above ]

Working:
========
library("rpart")
iris_tree <- rpart(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris)
pmml(iris_tree)
[ I am getting a PMML output over here]
```

I am using R on windows(64bit)-version 3.0.2.

Many thanks in advance if some one figures out why its happening?

Answer (score 1):

The pmml package currently does not have support for exporting ctree objects from party. I'm not aware of any immediate plans to do so or any alternatives, but it would probably only take a few hours for a good R coder to implement it (and then add it into the pmml package :-).